# Can't create Docker volume using absolute path on Linux

Tags: linux, docker, docker-volume

I'm getting the following error message when trying to run a Docker container with which I want to share some data via a directory (I added the emphasis):

> ##[error]/usr/bin/docker: Error response from daemon: create -v **/opt/vsts/work/1/s/coverage**: "-v /opt/vsts/work/1/s/coverage" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. **If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.**

What I don't understand is, that to my knowledge `/opt/vsts/work/1/s/coverage` is an absolute path, as indicated by the first forward slash.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the actual `docker run` command line you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A build script was passing in "-v /opt/vsts/work/1/s/coverage" as the actual name, i.e.

`docker run -v -v /opt/vsts/work/1/s/coverage:[...]`

instead of

`docker run -v /opt/vsts/work/1/s/coverage:[...]`.

Thanks @larsks for pointing me in the right direction.